# Constructing multi dimensional array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Working with [Dashin.io](http://dashing.io) framework to create some nice graphs. I'm trying to construct a specific array output that the application is looking for and I'm very close, but think I need help creating another dimension of the array.

This is what I have:

```
r = Redis.new(:host => "127.0.0.1", :password => 'password')
assGroups=['group1','group2', 'group3', 'group4']
points = ['Day', 'group1','group2', 'group3', 'group4']

history = 3
i = 0

while i <= history do
    getdate = (Date.today-i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    i += 1
    countArr=[getdate]
    points.push(countArr)

    for group in assGroups
        query = [getdate,":",group].join()
        queue = r.hgetall query
        dCount = queue['incidents'].to_i
        countArr << dCount
    end
end
print points
```

This is giving me

```
["Day", "group1","group2", "group3", "group4", ["2016-06-06", 63, 13, 86, 13], ["2016-06-05", 64, 13, 84, 13], ["2016-06-04", 63, 13, 84, 13], ["2016-06-03", 64, 13, 84, 13]]
```

This is very close but I need the, "Day" and groups its own dimension of the array as well, so this would be my desired output:

```
[["Day", "group1","group2", "group3", "group4"], ["2016-06-06", 63, 13, 86, 13], ["2016-06-05", 64, 13, 84, 13], ["2016-06-04", 63, 13, 84, 13], ["2016-06-03", 64, 13, 84, 13]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the simplest change would be to ensure `points` is a multidimensional array when you first define it:
`points = [['Day', 'group1','group2', 'group3', 'group4']]`

Comment: ahh yes much better then what I was trying with `unshift()` Thanks for the quick answer!